# Installing a TURN Server on Ubuntu for WebRTC

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc, rfc5766turnserver, coturn

How can I install a TURN server on my ubuntu 12.04? Can you share tutorial? I read this tutorial: [Implementing our own STUN/TURN server for WebRTC Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233980/implementing-our-own-stun-turn-server-for-webrtc-application). But what I don't understand is how I can I install my own TURN server on my ubuntu 12.04?

I am using currently using something like the following code to create the `RTCPeerConnection`

```js
const pc_config = {"iceServers": [{"url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},
  {"url":"turn:my_username@<turn_server_ip_address>", "credential":"my_password"}]};

const pc_new = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(pc_config);
```

And I want to fill the above code's arguments to work with a different network.

When i want to install turn server then I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package resiprocate-turn-server
```

I used `apt-get install resiprocate-turn-server`. I also used this https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html tutorial.

Comment: this shows minimal effort in actually trying to install a simple turn server....

Answer (score 37):

it is easy to install in linux machines, not tried in other OSes.

simple way:

```
sudo apt-get install coturn
```

If you say no, I want the latest cutting edge, you can download source code from their [downloads page](http://turnserver.open-sys.org/downloads/) in install it yourself, example:

```bash
sudo -i     # ignore if you already in admin mode
apt-get update && apt-get install libssl-dev libevent-dev libhiredis-dev make -y    # install the dependencies
wget -O turn.tar.gz http://turnserver.open-sys.org/downloads/v4.5.0.3/turnserver-4.5.0.3.tar.gz     # Download the source tar
tar -zxvf turn.tar.gz     # unzip
cd turnserver-*
./configure
make && make install
```

sample command for running TURN server:

```
sudo turnserver -a -o -v -n  --no-dtls --no-tls -u test:test -r "someRealm"
```

command description:

- -a - Use long-term credentials mechanism
- -o - Run server process as daemon
- -v - 'Moderate' verbose mode.
- -n - no configuration file
- --no-dtls - Do not start DTLS listeners
- --no-tls - Do not start TLS listeners
- -u - user credentials to be used
- -r - default realm to be used, need for TURN REST API

check this [wiki](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/turnserver) for more details and configurations.

now you can use the TURN server in your WebRTC application as:

```
var peerConnectionConfig = {
  iceServers: [{
    urls: YOUR_IP:3478,
    username: 'test',
    password: 'test'
  }]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to work with TCP ? Or it is only woks for the UDP.

Comment: yes, it is possible to work only with TCP but afraid the performance might be bad

Comment: Thank you for great solution. I am getting this error on mozilla firefox `uncaught exception: buildPeerConnection failed, call not completed` I am using easyRTC. Can you help me?

Comment: To skip IPv6 issue, enter the server IP. This worked for me like a charm: `turnserver -L <Your IP> -a -o -f -n  --no-dtls --no-tls -u username:password -r yourdomain.com`

Comment: I followed this process in one of my EC2 instance and found the TURN server is working fine. But in another EC2 instance I followed these steps too but it's not working when testing through https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ Here I should mention that both EC2 is running on Ubuntu 16.04 and all the incoming and outgoing ports or configuration are same. Not getting any clue. Can anyone suggest how can I figure out the issue? I tried by uninstall and reinstall but nothing working.

Comment: I want to enable support SSL certificates with this command. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: It returns 401 Unauthorised error still, it works! Any idea?

Answer (score 11):

On your ubuntu server machine, set up, configure & run [a packaged version of](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/coturn) [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn). For a basic setup, do

```bash
# set up
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes coturn

# configure & run
USERNAME="some-username"
PASSWORD="some-password"
PORT=3478

# -n: use only commandline parameters, no config file
sudo turnserver \
    -n \
    --verbose \
    --lt-cred-mech \
    --user $USERNAME:$PASSWORD \
    --realm "someRealm" \
    --no-dtls \
    --no-tls \
    --listening-port $PORT
```

Add `--daemon` to keep it running in the background.
See https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/turnserver for the list of options of `turnserver` and have a look at [their example config file](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/blob/master/examples/etc/turnserver.conf) if you want to use one with `-c CONFIGFILE` instead of using `-n` and passing all options on the commandline like I did above.

To check that it worked, in Google Chrome, while on any page of a secure origin (for example stackoverflow.com), run this in the developer console:

```js
function checkTURNServer(turnConfig, timeout){ 

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

    setTimeout(function(){
        if(promiseResolved) return;
        resolve(false);
        promiseResolved = true;
    }, timeout || 5000);

    var promiseResolved = false
      , myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection   //compatibility for firefox and chrome
      , pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers:[turnConfig]})
      , noop = function(){};
    pc.createDataChannel("");    //create a bogus data channel
    pc.createOffer(function(sdp){
      if(sdp.sdp.indexOf('typ relay') > -1){ // sometimes sdp contains the ice candidates...
        promiseResolved = true;
        resolve(true);
      }
      pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }, noop);    // create offer and set local description
    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){  //listen for candidate events
      if(promiseResolved || !ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !(ice.candidate.candidate.indexOf('typ relay')>-1))  return;
      promiseResolved = true;
      resolve(true);
    };
  });   
}

const USERNAME="some-username"
const PASSWORD="some-password"
const PORT=3478
const IP="10.11.0.115" // you will have to change this

console.log('TURN server reachable on TCP?', await checkTURNServer( {
    url: `turn:${IP}:${PORT}?transport=tcp`,
    username: USERNAME,
    credential: PASSWORD,
}))

console.log('TURN server reachable on UDP?', await checkTURNServer( {
    url: `turn:${IP}:${PORT}?transport=udp`,
    username: USERNAME,
    credential: PASSWORD,
}))
```

You should get

```
TURN server reachable on TCP? true
TURN server reachable on UDP? true
```

Comment: Worked for me, thanks :-). Side note, in case your server shows as unreachable, check if your server firewall is blocking the port

Comment: Needs to be updated, did not work on firefox. TurnConfig now takes `urls` arary instead of `url`:

    urls: [`turn:${IP}:${PORT}?transport=tcp`]

Answer (score 3):

I think the guide is somewhat outdated.

Look at this Google open source TURN server.
Really easy to install and works very well.
https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/

Comment: That's a legacy now

Answer (score 2):

This link will provide all details regarding installation and configuration of TURN server.

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html

The guy has very good repository for WebRtc demos.

Answer (score 0):

Turn Server Installation

change the package according to your server

```
wget http://turnserver.open-sys.org/downloads/v3.2.4.4/turnserver-3.2.4.4-debian-wheezy-ubuntu-mint-x86-64bits.tar.gz

tar -zxvf turnserver-3.2.4.4-debian-wheezy-ubuntu-mint-x86-64bits.tar.gz

wget http://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz

tar -zxvf libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz

cd libevent-2.0.21-stable/

./configure

make && make install

dpkg -i rfc5766-turn-server_3.2.4.4-1_amd64.deb

cd /etc/

vi turnserver.conf
```

Add following to turn **server.conf**

```
listening-device=eth0
listening-ip=YOUR_IP_HERE
listening-port=3478
userdb=turnuserdb.conf
relay-device=eth0
realm=YOUR_REALM_IP_HERE
lt-cred-mech
log-file=/var/log/turnserver.log
```

Add the username and password on **turnuserdb.conf**

```
 vi turnuserdb.conf
```

in the following format

```
testuser:pass0wrd
```

To Start the Turn Server:

```
sh /data/start_turn_server.sh
```

To add new Turn User:

```
sh /data/ addTurnUser.sh
```

To See if the Turn Server is running :

```
ps aux | grep –I turn
```

The above command should list some processes as turnserver , if the TURN server is running properly.