# How to configure WebRTC on my own server?

Tags: android, python, ios, linux, webrtc

I want to create the mobile app with video call feature So I selected web RTC for it.

I got the excellent document for client side. But I am not getting how to configure the server for it.

iOS : https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Getting-started-with-WebRTC-on-iOS/

Android : https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Introduction-to-WebRTC-on-Android/

Please share your experience guys.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a turn/stun server. This is the version used in the most online tutorials.
https://github.com/coturn/coturn
Just follow the install steps in the documentations

or you can look for a public stun server for testing purposes.

Comment: thanks for reply. I can't see any document in the repo shared by you.

Comment: Check the CoturnConfig page. You can also google a public stun server in your region for testing purposes.

Comment: is there any other easy document for it. As I am new for this. So, its very difficult for me to understand all this things.

Comment: You must have a linux os. So if you have ubuntu you can try this solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546098/installing-turn-server-on-ubuntu-for-webrtc   . It seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: STUN server is configured but its not working. is thr any specific stuff to check whether server has started video streaming ?