# WebRTC no video with some networks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrtc, simplewebrtc, signalmaster

I create web app with Ruby on Rails using WebRTC for video connections (with SimpleWebRTC: https://simplewebrtc.com/). It works on remote server, and use signalmaster (https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster). Everything works good on most networks, but sometimes there is no remote video. I have callback from `videoAdded`, but there is completely no video from other peers. I think it might be something with that network configuration, but have no idea what. Does anyone have idea what's wrong?

Comment: Do you use a TURN server? On some networks (symmetric NAT, Firewall...) it is mandatory to use one in order to initiate WebRTC calls.

Comment: That's it, just set up a TURN serveur. Follow the mido's answer at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233980/implementing-our-own-stun-turn-server-for-webrtc-application/35452566#35452566

Comment: Check out my answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/44432973/813988