# How to fix unreliable WebRTC calling?

Tags: cordova, webrtc, simplewebrtc, coturn, signalmaster

WebRTC calls are not reliable in our application. Sometimes we see the black screen, sometimes we don’t see call start at all and sometimes there are seen huge delays or de-sync in audio/video.

Setup:

- Google’s public STUN server `stun:stun.l.google.com:19302`;
- TURN server is `Coturn` hosted in azure in docker;
- Signaling server is a customized https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster that using express as a web server
- On client JS is used, with `simplewebrtc` as client;
- For iOS support used Cordova plugin - https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc

Almost **100% reproduced issue is calling from one client on LTE to another on Wi-Fi**. In this case we see black screen on both devices, however, default bg-color is white, so at least something happens on WebRTC side.

What was done to address issues:

- Examined Coturn logs... Sometimes we see "Unauthorized" errors there, but it's hard to say if they affect anything;
- Checked Coturn's traffic: in Wi-Fi to Wi-Fi scenarios it is low, so peer-to-peer connection is really made. If there is LTE, we see around 40–120KiB/sec load (Isn't that too low for audio/video?), so TURN seems to work;
- Checked client app logs, nothing special;

**Please, suggest any possible way of research or fix to make WebRTC as much reliable as possible.**

Comment: have you verified that your turn server actually works? See example #2 [here](http://testrtc.com/webrtc-api-trace/)

Comment: @PhilippHancke When there's no peer-to-peer connection we see some traffic through TURN server, 40-120KiB/sec. And this peak matches with calling.

Comment: 40-120kbps are too low for a audio/video call. Besides, TURN is a fallback so won't be used when direct connectivity works. The easiest way to check this is to stop the turn server while the connection is up -- if the call continues it is not using the TURN server

Comment: @PhilippHancke just tested and the call really stopped. However, we saw ~ 200–250KiB traffic now. Still was not very good quality.

Answer (score 2):

[image: WebRTC Connection Process]

The above scheme is from [this article](https://blog.addpipe.com/troubleshooting-webrtc-connection-issues/) I wrote which goes into a lot of detail on this topic.

Shortly, problems can appear in any of the 3 steps:

1. signaling
2. discovery using STUN/TURN
3. p2p connection

**Here's what I would do:**

1. Use a low minimum resolution in constraints like 320x240, this will make sure there are no simple to avoid [getUserMedia() errors](https://youtu.be/sjxtdknpgoQ?t=12m14s)
2. Make sure signaling is done over port 80 or 443
3. In many cases a peer can not communicate *with* the STUN/TURN servers so try  communicating with STUN/TURN using TCP (`stun:stun.l.google.com:19302?transport=tcp`) and port 80 (default is UDP port 3478 or 19302 for Google's STUN and they might be blocked by your router/firewall/proxy/mobile network )
4. Use [TrickleICE](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) (with your own STUN/TURN) and the [WebRTC Troubleshooter](https://test.webrtc.org/) on the LTE/WiFi devices and you'll learn a lot about how they can be connected *to*