# EasyRTC / WebRtc - Video call in 3G not working

Tags: javascript, webrtc, stun, turn, easyrtc

I've implemented a working video chat app using EasyRTC as framework.

If I make video call through my Wi-Fi internet connection, everything is working. When I make a video call through 3G internet connection, I can see list of connected user, but when I start video call to a listed one, I can't see any video or listen any audio (but message exchange is working).

Is it possible that mobile data network carrier limits p2p traffic of video call?

Comment: Do you use a TURN server? On some networks (symmetric NAT, Firewall...) it is mandatory to use one in order to initiate WebRTC calls

Comment: No. Actually I'm using this configuration:
`easyrtc.setOption(
 "appIceServers", [
        {'url': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'},
        {'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}
    ]
);`

Is there any TURN server free to use for development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are correct. Some networks block WebRTC flows.

You only have STUN servers. That's why you will need a TURN server in order to relay the media flows. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233980/implementing-our-own-stun-turn-server-for-webrtc-application/35452566#35452566) will provide you a method in order to deploy a TURN server.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Actually for development test I'm using a free account made from this site: [http://numb.viagenie.ca/](http://numb.viagenie.ca/)